# How to delete uploaded files PHP ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to delete a file uploaded after I click on a submit button or after the page is reloaded.

I did this drop zone to drag and drop file:

```
     <div id="drop_file_zone" class="centered" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">
        <div id="drag_upload_file" class="centered">
           <p><strong>Drop file here</strong></p>
           <p>or</p>
           <p>
              <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="selectfile3" type="button" value="Select File" onclick="file_explorer();" />
           </p>
           <input type="file" id="selectfile"/>
           <div class="img-content" style="text-align: center;"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

On my drag_drop.js file:

```
var fileobj;
function upload_file(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   fileobj = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
   ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
}

function file_explorer() {
   document.getElementById('selectfile').click();
   document.getElementById('selectfile').onchange = function () {
      fileobj = document.getElementById('selectfile').files[0];
      ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
   };
}

function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
   if (file_obj != undefined) {
      var form_data = new FormData();
      form_data.append('file', file_obj);
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("POST", "/app/helpers/upload_file.php", true);
      xhttp.onload = function (event) {
         oOutput = document.querySelector('.img-content');
         if (xhttp.status == 200) {
            if(this.responseText == 'false'){
               console.log('no type');
            } else {
               oOutput.innerHTML = "<img src='/app/assets/img/pdf.png' alt='The Image' width='32' height='32'/><p>" + this.responseText + "</p>";
            }
         } else {
            oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + xhttp.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.";
         }
      }

      xhttp.send(form_data);
   }
}
```

And on the upload_file.php this function:

```
<?php
$arr_file_types = ['application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];

if (!(in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $arr_file_types))) {
   echo "false";
   return;
}

if (!file_exists('uploads')) {
   mkdir('uploads', 0777);
}

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $filename);


echo $filename;
die;
```

but I don't really know how to delete these temps documents when I press the button (this button will save the document on a database) or when the page is reloaded.

Comment: If you just keep the files in the temp folder (not using `move_uploaded_file()`), the file should automatically be deleted when the script ends. Why do you want to store the files in a database instead of the file system though? That's usually not a good idea.

Comment: So, is it better to just keep the file name on the db and save the files on the file system?
And then, how do I access again to this temp folder to find the temp uploaded file?

Comment: If you want to store the file in the database, then just read it from the temp file and leave it and it will be deleted. If you only want to store the file name in the database and store the file on disc (recommended), then use `move_uploaded_file()` to move it from the temp file to where you want it to be. Then you can just read the file from that folder, using the name from the database.

Comment: yes, store the file name in the database. to access the file again, grab it from wherever you are moving it to with `move_uploaded_file()` consider however not storing these uploaded files in a publicly exposed folder, or at least checking the file extensions first, otherwise someone could upload 'rootkit.php' and navigate to it to make your server run whatever code they want.